# Create all possible words from an Array

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I want to create a recursive function that will create all the possible words from an array (dictionary)
Just to clarify , by words i mean string , for example "aab" is a word in that case.

```
char letters[36] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

By the way, I don't want an infinite amount of words, the max length will be 10.

So far I have this code:

```
char letters[36] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    char s[10]="";
    s[9]='\0';
    int l=0;
    printf("test \n");
    recur(s,letters,l);
```

And the recursive function:

```
int recur(char * mot , char * tab,int l){
    printf("int : %i \n",l);
    if(l<2) {

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tab); ++i) {
            mot[l]=tab[i];
            printf("%s \n",mot);
            l=l+1;
            recur(mot,tab,l);
        }    
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

But I dont have any problems starting again from scratch.

**EDIT:**

The result is want is something like this :

length == 1

```
a
b
c
d
.
.
8
9
```

length == 2

```
aa
ab
ac
.
c7
c8
.
.
99
```

And another example : `cd7e` for length == 4

**EDIT**

I changed my code to :
( to test all strings , max length = 2 )

```
int recur(char * mot , char * tab,int l){

    if(l<2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 36; ++i) {
            mot[l]=tab[i];
            printf("%s \n",mot);
            recur(mot,tab,l+1);
        }

    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And the results is

> a  aa  ab  ac  ad  ae  af  ag  ah  ai ....

It's skipping the length 1 strings i dont know why.

**EDIT**

I tried for `l<3` and this is the result :

> a  aa  aaa  aab  aac  aad  aae ...
>   a91  a92  a93  a94  a95  a96  a97  a98  a99  b99  ba9  baa  bab  bac 
>   bad  bae  baf  bag  bah  bai  baj  bak  bal  bam  ban ...

For length < 3 , it's skipping all the strings with a length = 1,2

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160003/discussion-on-question-by-quentin-oternaud-create-all-possible-words-from-an-arr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: reset your string delimiter after each recursion:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 36; ++i)
{
    mot[l]=tab[i];
    printf("%s \n",mot);
    recur(mot,tab,l+1);
}
mot[l] = '\0';
```

What happens is, you start with an empty `mot` array:

```
mot = "\0\0\0..."
```

then there is the first recursion depth:

```
mot = "a\0\0..."
```

second depth (final depth for `l<2` condition):

```
mot = "aa\0..."
...
mot = "a9\0..."
```

back to first depth you get:

```
mot = "b9\0..."
```

but you need:

```
mot = "b\0\0..."
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i understand what you just said but even with your fix it still skip most of the other strings : 

a 
aa 
aaa 
aab 
aac 
aad 
aae 
aaf 
aag 
aah 
aai 
aaj 
aak 
aal 
aam 
aan 
aao 
aap 
aaq 
aar 
aas 
aat 
aau 
aav 
aaw 
aax 
aay 
...
a95 
a96 
a97 
a98 
a99 
b 
ba 
baa 
bab 
bac 
bad 
bae 
baf 
bag 
bah 
bai

Comment: @QuentinOternaud no, its just a different order... `b` will come after `a99`. You didn't mention any specific order to be required.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code. This is complete working code:
[**Note:** See it [working here](https://ideone.com/Y9RWFZ)]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

/* Function to print permutations of string
   This function takes three parameters:
   1. String
   2. Starting index of the string
   3. Ending index of the string. */
void permute(char *a, int l, int r)
{
   int i;
   if (l != r)
   {
       for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
           {
              swap((a+l), (a+i));
              permute(a, l+1, r);
              swap((a+l), (a+i)); //backtrack
           }
   }
   else
   {
       printf("%s\n", a);
   }
}

/* arr[]  ---> Input Array
   data[] ---> Temporary array to store current combination
   start & end ---> Staring and Ending indexes in arr[]
   index  ---> Current index in data[]
   r ---> Size of a combination to be printed */
void combinationUtil(char alphas[], char data[], int start, int end,
                     int index, int count)
{
    int i;
    if (index == count)
    {
        data[count] = '\0';
        permute(data, 0, count-1);
        return;
    }

    for (i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= count-index; i++)
    {
        data[index] = alphas[i];
        combinationUtil(alphas, data, i+1, end, index+1, count);
    }
}

// The main function that prints all combinations of size r
// in arr[] of size n. This function mainly uses combinationUtil()
void printCombination(char alphas[], int n, int count)
{
    int data[count+1];
    combinationUtil(alphas, data, 0, n-1, 0, count);
}

int main()
{
    char alphas[] = "ABCD"; //Provide here the characters which you wants to use
    int i;
    int len = strlen(alphas);
    for(i = 0; i<len; i++)
        printCombination(alphas, len, i+1);
    return 0;
}
```

This is combination of code available at following links of [geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org):

[Create *Permutation*](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/)

[Create *Combination*](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/)